# Remove paint from concrete floor (indoors)

Tags: concrete

I'm trying to find a solution to prep my concrete floors (slab) for tile.

A contractor I had hired to remodel my home did an outstanding painting job -- so well that he managed to cover most of my floor in kills paint/primer that is now peeling and is a lovely mess to clean up. What a nice guy :)

Anyways, I'm looking at various solutions mentioned on Various Google search results. It seems like paint remove is a good way to go but requires hosing / pressure washing afterwards. Unfortunately this is my dining and living rooms and I don't believe I can contain the water.

Some mention using a grinder but I feel like the paint would just cake on it and it wouldn't be very affective.

Any suggestions?

Comment: No direct experience, so won't make this an answer, but I'd think a grinder with a stiff wire brush attachment would knock off the loose stuff and score the rest enough to get fresh paint to bite. Get a good mask/ eye protection (wires fly!) and serious cleanup afterwards (hepa filter in shopvac).

Answer (score 1):

For mechanical removal of paint from floors....

If you're talking about drips/splatters/spills that are on the floor from painting the walls/ceiling you can use wire or bristle disks that are meant for removing paint/rust and there's also the Wagner [Paint Eater](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Wagner-4-1-2-in-Paint-Eater-Disc-Sander-0513040/202102612).

If you're talking about the whole floor covered in paint you can rent a floor sander with an abrasive diamond pad or a shot blaster.

All of them are messy and generate a lot of dust. Shot blaster also removes any weak/soft concrete at the surface which could improve your tile adhesion.